# Python continuous parallel execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing, stdin

Looking to build a python script that runs an infinite read loop from stdin like `for line in sys.stdin:`. For each iteration, I would like to get a worker from a pool that executes in the background using `line` as input. The process on finishing its execution or timing out prints to stdout.

I am having a difficult time finding a worker pool module that is able to work continuously. For example, the [multiprocess pool module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) only supports functions like `join` that wait for all workers to finish all tasks. For the above specification, I cannot know all the tasks ahead of time and need to assign work as it comes to processes in the background.

Comment: You can use a separate Process that consumes from a Queue the results from the workers (Process as well), printing it to stdout.

Comment: Restating the idea... Each line is added to a queue. Then each process continuously checks the queue for a line. (Do I need to lock the queue so multiple processes do not remove the same line from the queue?). Then if there is a line, a process will remove it from the queue and print the result to stdout after which it returns to looking at the queue? How do I force a process to timeout if the work takes too long and to move on? Do you know of any examples online?

Comment: You have your mainloop spawning Process(..., args=(queue, line)) as each new line arrives. Meanwhile a previously spanwed Process consumes the Queue and prints the results. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: From what it looks like you are saying, every line spawns a new process with a queue? How do I reuse processes so that every line does not create a new process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run forever.

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()

for line in sys.stdin.readline():
    pool.apply_async(function, args=[line])

def function(line):
    """Process the line in a separate process."""
    print(line)
```

Comment: Hey! I am pretty sure this does not work. Have you tried it? I tried something like this with a loop from 1 to 10. The apply_async does not actually start executing the task.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Pool` and `imap` might make it easier, but you have to assume a maximum capacity of workers (`processes=5`):

```
import multiprocessing
import sys


def worker(line):
    return "Worker got %r" % (line)


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
for result in pool.imap(worker, sys.stdin):
    print "Result: %r" % (result)
```